# Can't get response from HttpWebRequest in C#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-403

The error says:

> "The remote server returned an error:
>   (http://www.tgv.com.my/movies/man-city-v-arsenal-HO00005174)
>   Forbidden"

below is my code:

```
string url = https://translate.google.com/translate_a/single?client=t&sl=en&tl=vi&hl=vi&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qca&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&dt=at&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&otf=1&srcrom=1&ssel=0&tsel=0&kc=5&tk=520987|10880&q=" + keyword;
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
WebProxy proxy = (WebProxy)WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
if (proxy.Address != null)
{
    proxy.Credentials = proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pw");
    WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(proxy.Address, proxy.BypassProxyOnLocal, proxy.BypassList, proxy.Credentials);
}

request.Proxy = proxy;
var postData = "";
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36";
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
return responseString;
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you trying to get a response from `www.google.com` ?

Comment: I already tried it with www.google.com. But not OK :(. Thanks!

Comment: POSTing "" to the root url is not going to work.  What do you actually want to do?

Comment: You also leave several things undisposed.

Comment: Hi Alex K,
The url : https://translate.google.com/translate_a/single?client=t&sl=en&tl=vi&hl=vi&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qca&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&dt=at&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&otf=1&srcrom=1&ssel=0&tsel=0&kc=5&tk=520987|10880&q=" + keyword

Comment: Isn't it a normal GET request on google translate?

Answer (score 0):

Using your Url, it's not a `POST` request, it's a `GET` request and could be done like this:

```
string url = "https://translate.google.com/translate_a/single?client=t&sl=de&tl=en&hl=de&dt=at&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qca&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&otf=2&ssel=0&tsel=0&kc=4&tk=767774.885916&q=hallo%20du";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

But if your `q` should have another value, other values must be changed too, otherwise you will have the `Error 403` whitch tells you, that you do not have permission to do your request.

Using Google Translate, consider having a look at the [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/quickstart). 
There you can do your request like that:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=YOUR_API_KEY&q=hello%20world&source=en&target=de
```

But this is a payd service...